# using RealityKit PhotogrammetrySession with bounding box geometry crashes

Tags: realitykit

im using the sample code from apple for the photogrammetry session to demonstrate:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/creating_a_photogrammetry_command-line_app

It all works, BUT when I try to add the geometry parameter to it, it crashes/Stops in an internal break point.

The original code looks like:

```
if let detailSetting = detail {
            return PhotogrammetrySession.Request.modelFile(url: outputUrl, 
                                                      detail:  detailSetting)
} else {
```

As soon as I add a boundary box, the code crashes/stops at an internal breakpoint.
For the demonstration I added the bounding box that got calculated by the session manually

```
if let detailSetting = detail {
           let bx = BoundingBox(min: SIMD3<Float>(-0.5131897, -0.36881575 -0.35893312),
                                max: SIMD3<Float>(0.5131897, 0.36881575, 0.35893312))
            let geom:  PhotogrammetrySession.Request.Geometry? =
                             PhotogrammetrySession.Request.Geometry(
                                             bounds: bx, transform: Transform.identity)

            return PhotogrammetrySession.Request.modelFile(url: outputUrl, 
                                  detail: detailSetting,
                                  geometry: geom)
} else {
```

I know I had the bounding box working before, but I don't see why it stopped.
Does anyone know if that is a known problem in a softwareupdate or something else out of my control?

The debugger shows:
[image: break]

The output is unsuspicious:
[image]

And the backtrace is
[image]
[image]

not useful to me.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be fixed with Monteray 12.3